# Macchanger address change won't stay

Tags: mac

I ran:

```
sudo macchanger -r wlan0
sudo macchanger -m xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx wlan0
```

Both of these commands produce a change as confirmed with both `ifconfig wlan0` and `macchanger -s wlan0`.

But after I connect to a router--or after a few minutes--the MAC address always reverts back to default.

Anybody know how to get `macchanger` working?

Comment: Is it possible after all these years someone found a solution to this? The same happens to me in Mint, no matter how I spoof it; custom set or random. I know it's a long shot, but any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough points to comment yet or I'd post this as a comment.

Could you have something locking you in you udev rules?

```
 sudo less /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules
```

This caches the MAC address and interface name for you system. I've been burned by it before when changing out network cards then swapping them back.

Check if the MAC in the rules file is the one you are getting reset back too.

Comment: Hm, sudo shouldn't be needed to view a file.

Comment: You are correct. Sudo is for when you edit it next.